# Unable to complete Windows Phone Certificate enrollment web service process

Tags: mdm

I am implementing windows phone MDM using windows phone 8 enterprise DM Protocol. I succeed in Discovery phase and  Certificate enrolment policy web service. But in Certificate enrolment web service process i am facing problem.
While creating  provisioning XML i embedded my domain CA and intermediate certificates. I also added Client certificate which i got request from device. I totally converted into base 64 format and i am sending response to the device(RequestSecuirtyTokenResponse). I am using Fiddler tool for seeing logs .
I am not getting any response from the device.
My doubts are 1) what certificates i need use in provisioning XML  . 2) what is client certificate.
 I am using valid ssl not self sign certificate. Still i  need any certificates
Any advice would be greatly  appreciated. Please guide me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally after one month i succeed enrolment.

We have to use windows phone developer power tool for debugging.

For my questions i am answering as  below.

1) We have to use Root certificate(CA) that is valid CA certificate. We need to sign client certificate(fly from device) with server certificate and key certificate. Be careful about finger print.
2) No extra certificates need for enrolment. Above two are mandatory.

I hope above will helps to others.